# Is it safe to block in callback of CopyFileEx?

Tags: winapi, file-copying

The Windows API function CopyFileEx allows a callback function to be specified which is then being called when a part of the file has been copied to e.g. provide the user with feedback about the progress.

This works fine in my program, but I have now an additional requirement: I need to temporarily pause the copying process in order to keep system load low for a time (may be up to several hours) and then resume it. This may happen at any time and usually there is a large file (several 100 Gigabytes) that is only partly copied yet, so aborting the process and restarting it is not a good option, as that would mean that possibly 99% of a file that have already been copied, would need to be copied again.

One option to do that is simply let the thread that executes the copy sleep when the callback is called, e.g.

```
function ProgressCallback(
  _TotalFileSize, _TotalBytesTransferred, _StreamSize,
  _StreamBytesTransferred: LARGE_INTEGER;
  _StreamNumber, _CallbackReason: LongWord;
  _SourceFile, _DestinationFile: THandle; _Data: Pointer): LongWord;
  far; stdcall;
begin
  // [...]
  while gblPauseFlag do
    sleep(100);
end;
```

(This is of course simplified code. The original is too complex to post here.) The gblPauseFlag would be set and reset by a different thread in the application that checks for the condition to pause.

I am aware that there are better ways to pause the thread (events, critical sections or whatever), but the question here is just: Is is safe to pause the copying thread in the callback function? Or would it block some Windows functionality or resources?

As you can see from the sample code, this is a Delphi program, but I don't think that matters much, so I have not tagged the question as [delphi].

EDIT: I could pass the flag COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE, but:

> Progress of the copy is tracked in the target file in case the copy fails.
>   The failed copy can be restarted at a later time by specifying the same
>   values for lpExistingFileName and lpNewFileName as those used in the call
>   that failed. **This can significantly slow down the copy operation** as the
>   new file may be flushed multiple times during the copy operation.

Source: [CopyFileEx documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852(v=vs.85).aspx)

So I would rather try to avoid this.

Comment: this is safe. you suspend only your thread in this case.

Comment: WTF was my question downvoted? Please leave at least a comment explaining that vote!

Comment: You should probably explain, why the obvious solution (returning `PROGRESS_STOP` from your [CopyProgresssRoutine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363854.aspx)) doesn't work for you.

Comment: @IInspectable This requires the `COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE` flag. From the reference: _"This can significantly slow down the copy operation"_

Comment: @zett42: That would be a valid reason. It is still required for the OP to explain, why the obvious solution doesn't work for them. Maybe they are fine with the slowdown, maybe they are not, or maybe the API does not work as documented for them. We don't know. And since the OP was asking, why this Q was down-voted, that may be something to consider, if they are planning to improve the question.

Comment: @IInspectable done.

Comment: That's better, yet still I wasn't necessarily hoping for a decision based on speculation. Have you measured, that it really *is* significantly slower in your use case? Have you verified, that - even if it is slower - it is not fast enough for you?

Comment: From a quick look at [`CopyFile2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449404(v=vs.85).aspx), it's callback can return [`COPYFILE2_PROGRESS_PAUSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449417(v=vs.85).aspx), which doesn't require the `COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE` flag (it is explicitly stated that both flags are mutually exclusive). The function is available since Windows 8.

Comment: @zett42 thanks, but that does not answer the question (and does not solve my problem, because the system in question is still running Windows XP and cannot be updated. (no, there is no Internet connection so it is reasonably safe)). But that's definitely an option once we can update.

Comment: I don't see how it would hurt. File I/O isn't guaranteed to complete in any given amount of time, after all.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Couldn't it trigger a timeout, e. g. when a file is copied over the network?

Comment: no any reason think that call sleep/wait from callback not safe. `CopyFileEx` (synchronous routine) in loop copy file chunks and call callback after every chunk copy (in current thread). no any reason call this callback in process wide critical section (which can affect something else in process). otherwise this will be how minimum documented. so we can just wait/sleep in callback. from another case - i test with `COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE` and `PROGRESS_STOP` in callback.. may be i somethink not understand - but target file is deleted after `PROGRESS_STOP`.

Comment: as result when next time `CopyFileEx` called - it not restarted but begin from 0. not work at all restart

Comment: @RbMm This is confirmed by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889131/copyfileex-in-windows-7).

Comment: @zett42 - yes, begin from win7 i view the same as in your link

Answer (score -1):

Ideally when you have such a large to copy, you should be using utility like [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) for large files. If you still prefer to write your own utility, make it such that you can restart the aborted copy. You can use the file stream to store metadata about your progress of your copy in the destination file.

Comment: Robocopy is not an option here. I need to use my own program because it communicates with other programs on that computer to know what to copy (and more important: What *not* to copy) and when to pause.